# in hadoop, how does reduce task pull data from map task

Tags: java, hadoop

I understand that reducer pulls map output through http. But since each map task mergers all its spills to one file, how can a reduce task pull those intermediate data from map task? Just a piece of that file?

Answer (score 1):

The output of map tasks are sorted by partition number. Each partition number corresponds to  one reducer. When a a reducer pulls the output, the file pointer will be offset to the starting position of the partition number for the reducer and start reading. Of course, some partition number to file offset table is maintained on the mapper side to achieve this.

Comment: from the code, it looks like map task finishes after merging all the spill files. How can the "some partition number to file offset table" be maintained in this way though? Too, I can see in the ReduceTask, it opens a http connection to fetch the intermediate data, but I don't see any http handler on the map task side. Does the TaskTracker serve as a http server to handle the reduce http request? I doubt it.

Comment: At the end of map, the output(either multiple spills or 1 spill) is sorted by partition number. The partition number to file offset table is written as well. This table is not kept in memory. Current Hadoop(1.0/0.20.xxx) is using jetty to sever the HTTP request. Jetty can be started in a thread. You have to read the code for more details. Current trunk is using netty instead of jetty.